# How to install node package on MacBook for Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, xcode11.3, macbookpro-touch-bar

I have downloaded Node from [Here](https://nodejs.org/en/) for MacBook. Now when I double click on package, it is giving me error.

[image: Node Installation Error]

Anyone knows about this ?

Or can you give me other way to install node on MacBook ?

Comment: there's a forum for Mac stuff on [StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) for this kind'a questions, this is nothing about code! But on a mac, just old Option key while opening to enable the install option when installing application not signed, or Right-click and select "Open"...

Comment: belongs to https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It used be fine. But then I haven’t tried to download directly from their site for a while.
Since I have a need to install multiple versions of node and switch between them, I used `nodenv` installed via Homebrew. Another popular tool people use is `nvm`.
You can follow simple instruction at https://brew.sh/ to install Homebrew and you can install node by `brew install node`. If you want to be able to switch between versions, you can install nodenv by following Homebrew install steps at https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv/blob/master/README.md. Then install node by `nodenv install 12.16.1`